# Android Studio Section Pager Fragment Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I want to make an app that has multiple tabs that I can slide between.
I choose the Tabbed Acitivity with Action Bar Tabs (with ViewPager) navigation tabs.

I am trying to make each tab correspond with a fragment. So I can change the lay-out of each fragment etc.

A part of my fragment code is:

```
public class Page1Fragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;


public Page1Fragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
```

*This is not the complete code

In my SeciontsPagerAdapter, this is my getItem method.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

    // return MainActivity.PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    switch(position){
        case 0:
            return new Page1Fragment();
        case 1:
            return new Page2Fragment();
        case 2:
            return new Page3Fragment();
        case 3:
            return new Page4Fragment();
    }
    return null;
}
```

But I get an error? It says Page1Fragment can't be converted to a Fragment?
But I let Page1Fragment extends from Fragment?

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: did you import this `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this:

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return new GamesFragment1();//.newInstance(0);
        case 1:
            return new GamesFragment2();//.newInstance(1);
        case 2:
            return new GamesFragment3();//.newInstance(2);

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Page1Fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.PageTransformer;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two fragment classes either you have to use support library class or app.fragment class. don't mix it up

Answer (score 0):

You need to import below

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
```

Did you add this ?

1. `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;`
2. Set`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`